# Loop won't cycle through matrix

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, matrix

I can't figure out why this function won't cycle through all the inputs in the associated class matrix it only examines the first field.  I have a feeling it is because I am missing a [i] somewhere, but I tried putting it a couple different places and got no or strange results.

```
function showAnamneseFisico()
{
  function nullCheck() { 
    var y =  /^\d{7}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}/;
    var x = $(".nidNumber");
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
 if (y.test(x.val()) === false){ 
 return 0;}
}

   if (nullCheck() === 0) {
     alert ('pop');}
}
```

Comment: What matrix are you referring to?

Comment: Add {} to your for loop?

Comment: @technophobia To my understanding, and I may be using the wrong terminology, but the $(".nidNumber") should create a matrix array of input answers with the class nidNumber that the for loop should cycle through measuring each of those input answers against the if statement.

Comment: @JoshuaViele You're correct, the terminology is a little off. The more appropriate term for it is a _collection_ or a _set_.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the matrix refers to all elements with the class `.nidNumber`, then:

```
function showAnamneseFisico() {
    var y =  /^\d{7}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}/;
    var x = $(".nidNumber");
    var isNull =  false;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (y.test(x.eq(i).val()) === false){ 
            isNull = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isNull) {
        alert ('pop');
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- Nested method `nullCheck()` was replaced with a `isNull` boolean
- Used [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to extract the element needed
- Broke out of the for loop as soon as a false value was found

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks, AND you solved the nested function method I have been trying to figure out to boot!  I have that generic nullCheck function all throughout my code and now I can clean it all up